# MongoDB full text search and lookup operator

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Full text search in MongoDB seems to be a nice feature, especially when it comes to the need of high performance search and indexes. 
However, I am wondering why a full text search is not allowed over more than one collection.

For example: I have a supplier and a products collection (every supplier has n products) I would really like to do a search over all products, but the name of the supplier should also be matched.
Right now I am doing this with a $lookup and then a match with a regular expression. This works, but its very slowly (500 - 800ms).

If I used a full text search with an index, this would increase performance significantly. But the $text-operator has to be the first stage in the aggregation pipeline, not allowing me to use a $lookup first.

(See restrictions-section: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text)

Any ideas how I could increase the speed of a text search over multiple collections?

Answer (score 2):

for someone who still looking for solution

```
db.getCollection('projects').aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "$text": {"$search": query }
    }}, {
    "$lookup": {
        "from":         "users",
        "localField":   "uuid",
        "foreignField": "uuid",
        "as":           "user"
    }}, {
        "$sort": {
            "score": { "$meta": "textScore" }
        }
    }]);
```

where query is a text search string.

This query is for `projects` collection with key `uuid`, which refers to `users` collection with `uuid` key, all sorted by relevance.

Comment: A very useful example! Furthermore, adding `"$addFields": {"score": { "$meta": "textScore" }}` to the array shows the `score` field in the result.